# Making a Pen's LineCap go more into the drawn Line/Curve

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Currently I have the following code:

```
  AdjustableArrowCap arrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(10, 15, false);
  penStateOutline.CustomEndCap = arrow;
```

And it draws this:

[image]

I have tried all day to make the arrow point to the ellipse itself rather than the center of it..

Comment: What are the arguments for the `AdjustableArrowCap` constructor? Position?

Comment: (width,height,filled)

Comment: What's the code doing the drawing from within `AdjustableArrowCap`? I'm assuming it's the object doing the actual drawing? If so, that's where you need to make changes

Comment: I'm setting a Pen object's _CustomEndCap_ to the _AdjustableArrowCap_ which is a part of System.Drawing(I did not make it)

The pen is later used by Graphics..

Comment: In this instance, you'd be better off then implementing your own version. I don't think it exposes the required values to cap the line in the manner you want

Comment: The problem is, That I am going to be using this with _DrawCurve_ as well..

I do not know how to fit it to curves..

Comment: Somebody painted a circle on top of it, hard to see.  Consider making the line shorter by the circle radius or drawing the circle before drawing the line.

Comment: -_- Read the comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much to @TaW for helping.
Unfortunately the answer he provided did not match my stupid OCD..

You made me think about the problem from a different perspective and I now have found a solution that I'll share if anyone else needs, note that the solution is not perfect.

```
public static Point ClosestPointOnCircle(int rad, PointF circle, PointF other)
    {
        if (other.X == circle.X && other.Y == circle.Y) // dealing with division by 0
            other.Y--;

        return new Point((int)Math.Floor(circle.X + rad * ((other.X - circle.X) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(other.X - circle.X, 2) + Math.Pow(other.Y - circle.Y, 2))))), (int)Math.Floor(circle.Y + rad * ((other.Y - circle.Y) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(other.X - circle.X, 2) + Math.Pow(other.Y - circle.Y, 2))))));
    }
```

What the code does is return a point on the circle that is the closest to the another point, then, I used the curve middle point as the other point to change the end point of the curve.
Then I used the arrow cap as normal and got this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0oYx.png)
Which is good enough for my project.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** (I was wrong about the cap extending the line; it doesn't!)

To let the line and its cap end at the cirlce's outside you need to  make the line shorter by the radius of the circle.

There are two approaches:

- You can **find a new endpoint** that sits on the circle by calculating it, either with Pythagoras or by trigonometry. Then replace the endpoint, i.e. the circle's center, when drawing the line or curve by that new point.

Or put the other way round: You need to calculate a point on the circle as the new endpoint of the line.

It requires a little math, unless the line is horizontal or vertical...

This will work well for straight lines but for curves it may cause considerable changes in the shape, depending on how close the points get and how curved the shape is.

This may **or may not** be a problem.

- To avoid it you can **replace the curve points by a series of line points** that are close enough to look like a curve when drawn. From the list of points we subtract all those that do not lie inside the circle.

This sounds more complicated than it is as there is a nice class called `GraphicsPath` that will allow you to add a curve and then flatten it. The result is a more or less large number of points. The same class also allows you to determine whether a point lies inside a shape, i.e. our case inside the circle.

---

To implement **the latter approach**, here is a routine that transforms a list of curve points to a list of line points that will end close to the circle..:

```
void FlattenCurveOutside(List<Point> points, float radius)//, int count)
{
    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    using (GraphicsPath gpc = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        // firt create a path that looks like our circle:
        PointF l = points.Last();
        gpc.AddEllipse(l.X - radius, l.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius* 2);
        // next one that holds the curve:
        gp.AddCurve(points.ToArray());
        // now we flatten it to a not too large number of line segments:
        Matrix m = new Matrix(); // dummy matrix
        gp.Flatten(m, 0.75f);   // <== play with this param!!

        // now we test the pathpoints from bach to front until we have left the circle:
        int k = -1;
        for (int i = gp.PathPoints.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if ( !gpc.IsVisible(gp.PathPoints[i])) k = i;
            if (k > 0) break;
        }
        // now we know how many pathpoints we want to retain:
        points.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
             points.Add(Point.Round(gp.PathPoints[i]));
    }
}
```

Note that when the last part of the curve is too straight the result may look a little jagged..

[image]

**Update 2**

To implement **the former approach** here is a function that returns a `PointF` on a circle of radius `r` and a line connecting a  `Point b` with the circle center `c`:

```
PointF Intersect(Point c, Point a, int rad)
{
    float dx = c.X - a.X;
    float dy = c.Y - a.Y;

    var radians =  Math.Atan2(dy, dx); 
    var angle = 180 - radians * (180 / Math.PI);
    float alpha =  (float)(angle * Math.PI / 180f);
    float ry = (float)(Math.Sin(alpha) * rad );
    float rx = (float)(Math.Cos(alpha) * rad );
    return new PointF(c.X + rx, c.Y - ry);
}
```

The result thankfully  looks rather similar:

[image]

The math can be simplified a little..

To apply it you can get the new endpoint and replace the old one:

```
PointF I = Intersect(c, b, r);
points2[points2.Count - 1] = Point.Round(I);
```

Comment: I was thinking that, But the line will probably be a curve..

That's why I went to EndCaps

Comment: Well the caps will extend the curve as well and will point in the last direction. you may want to add one helper point close to the end..

Comment: How would I go about doing that? With DrawCurve I just supply around 3 Points and it makes the curve by itself..  
How can I achieve the last angle with that?